# await not calling my method and it never returns

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I have following code which uses async await.

```
    private async void DoAction()
    {
        foreach (var ele in new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
        {
            int i = await LoadAction();
        }
    }

    private Task<int> LoadAction()
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(CalledFromAsync);
        return task;
    }

    private int CalledFromAsync()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return rand.Next();
    }
```

My CalledFromAsync() is never called. Am I doing anything wrong here? Please help me.

Comment: Note that while this is interesting as an example, this isn't necessarily an ideal use-case for `async`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning a task that never gets started. It is not a huge surprise that it never completes either. You need to use `task.Start();` to start the task, or any of the other factory methods like `Task.Run`.

Comment: I am expecting 'await' itself starts the task. Is it not correct?

Comment: @Adinarayana No, `await` is a mechanism to come back to a line of code after a task completes and optionally using the same `SynchronizationContext`, it has nothing to do with starting the task it is waiting on to finish.

Comment: @Adinarayana keep in mind that *most* of the time, the thing you are waiting on **isn't CPU** - it is an external resource (file, network, etc); so there is nothing to "start"

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for prompt response. Now I understood that await just waits for task to complete and does nothing with Task.

Comment: @Adinarayana important: `await` does not "wait"; it schedules something *as a continuation*, to be done when it *is* complete'

Answer (score 3):

As mark said, using `Task` constructor returns a "cold task" in a "created" state, which hasn't started execution.
 You should always use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.Startnew` when initiating a `Task`, which always return a "hot Task".

From the [`TAP Guidlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Task Status:**
>
> To support corner cases of types that derive from `Task` and `Task<TResult>`, and to support the separation of construction from scheduling, the Task class exposes a `Start` method. Tasks that are created by the public Task constructors are referred to as cold tasks, because they begin their life cycle in the non-scheduled Created state and are scheduled only when Start is called on these instances. All other tasks begin their life cycle in a hot state, which means that the asynchronous operations they represent have already been initiated and their task status is an enumeration value other than `TaskStatus.Created`. **All tasks that are returned from TAP methods must be activated. If a TAP method internally uses a task’s constructor to instantiate the task to be returned, the TAP method must call Start on the Task object before returning it.** Consumers of a TAP method may safely assume that the returned task is active and should not try to call Start on any Task that is returned from a TAP method. Calling Start on an active task results in an `InvalidOperationException` exception.